# python: using multiprocessing with a dataframe for geocoding

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return the zipcode as column in a dataframe. This code works but doesn't create a new column in the dataframe gps.

```
import geocoder
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

google_key = 'key'

def reverse_gecode(coordinates):
    return geocoder.google(coordinates, key = google_key, method = 'reverse').postal

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    gps = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [27.950575, 40.6936488],
                        'lon': [-82.4571776, -89.5889864]})  # dataframe mehtod
    gps['gps'] = zip(gps.lat, gps.lon)
    x = list(gps['gps'])
    # multiprocessings                    
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    result_latlong = pool.map(reverse_gecode, x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I have tried

1. `gps['zip_code'] = gps.apply(lambda x: pool.map(reverse_gecode,
   list(x[2])), 
       axis = 1)`
2. `gps['zip_code'] = gps.apply(lambda x: pool.map(reverse_gecode, x[2]), 
   axis = 1)`
3. `gps['zip_code'] = gps.apply(lambda x: pool.map(reverse_gecode, [x[0], x[1]]), 
   axis = 1)`

But I just cannot get anything to work. The error I keep getting is

> ValueError: ('Unknown location: 27.950575', u'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try is:

```
import geocoder
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

def reverse_gecode(coordinates):
    return geocoder.google(coordinates, method = 'reverse').postal

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    gps = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [27.950575, 40.6936488],
                        'lon': [-82.4571776, -89.5889864]})  # dataframe mehtod
    coords = gps[['lat','lon']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]), axis=1).tolist()
    # multiprocessings                    
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    gps['zip_code'] = pool.map(reverse_gecode, coords)
    print(gps)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

PS i've removed `key=google_key` in the `geocoder.google()` call, because it didn't work for me

Output:

```
         lat        lon zip_code
0  27.950575 -82.457178    33602
1  40.693649 -89.588986    61603
```

Comment: I just checked it - it works properly for Python 3.5.1 and 2.7.11 (pandas: 0.18.0) - what versions do you have?

Comment: @dustin, what is the output of `print gps[['lat','lon']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]), axis=1)`

Comment: and `gps[['lat','lon']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]), axis=1).tolist()`?

Comment: then it must work! what line of code gives you `AttributeError` exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111040/discussion-between-maxu-and-dustin).